# Spark streaming Kafka application - performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, cloudera-cdh

I've a Spark streaming application (on CDH 5.8.4, Spark 1.6.0) that reads from two different Kafka topic, each partitioned by three.

Each DStream references to a different pipeline execution.

If I set 6 executor with 1 core each, I have the following performance:
[image]
Note that in this configuration, three executors are never used!

Otherwise, if I set 3 executor (with 1 core each), the performance time is increased 2x.
[image]

Someone can help me?

Edit:
I consume data from Kafka topic using the following code:

```
`    KafkaUtils
      .createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder, (String, Array[Byte])](
        streamingContext,
        kafkaParams,
        offset.get,
        { message: MessageAndMetadata[String, Array[Byte]] => (message.key(), message.message()) }
      )`
```

This code is used to read from each Kafka topic. I read data, process it, then write them to other Kafka topic and commit the offsets.

Reading and writing operations are executed with following properties:

```
`private val consumerProperties = new Properties()
  consumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", xxx)
  consumerProperties.put("group.id", xxx)
  consumerProperties.put("client.id", xxx)
  consumerProperties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false")
  consumerProperties.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000")
  consumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  consumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
  consumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset", xxx)`
```

Comment: Which consumer are you using? What's your job doing? Could you add the code?

Comment: I think you missed something with `code`?

Comment: I put the code into principal message :)